# Does Sitefinity support SAML 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, sitefinity, sitefinity-8

We have developed an Identity Provider to perform Single sign on using SAML 2.0.

I just want to know whether Sitefinity gives support for SAML protocols ?

- I came to know sitefinity supports only Claims based authentication(using WIF).
- And found something in Github link below,where sitefinity can extend to 3rd party STS/IDP like Google,FB,Amazon.

But these external auth are OAuth based(i guess).

https://github.com/Sitefinity/Sitefinity-External-STS-Integration/blob/master/README.md

Is it possible to use a SAML 2 IDP for performing SSO in sitefinity CMS?

Any suggestions,resource references will be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitefinity does not support SAML out of the box.

For more Reference,follow the link below

http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/developing-with-sitefinity-/does-sitefinity-support-saml-2-0

Answer (score 0):

And Sitefinity still doesn't support SAML 2.0. But using a package like this one I was able to add in support pretty easily using standard MVC Controllers and Actions and such: https://www.itfoxtec.com/IdentitySaml2

(I'm not affiliated with them, just a fan.)